# Should users repeatedly redirect askers to an external site for official support?

Tags: discussion, comments, etiquette

I have noticed that many questions with a specific tag on Stack Overflow are receiving a lot of comments by the same user that contain a link to the official repository from that open source library. This user (I am not sure if he is part of the maintainers) is asking to go there and formulate the question again.

These are rough examples of the comments I am referring to:

> Questions regarding recent version of the library should be asked here: github.com/xxx/xxx/issues

> Please search for discussions about it in github.com/xxx/xxx/issues or github.com/xxx/xxx/discussions. For example: github.com/xxx/xxx/issues/123. I think this is too specialized question to be answered in here :)

I am curious if this is an acceptable use of Stack Overflow. On one hand, it is great that users are being redirected to a resource where they can get more in-depth help and support. On the other hand, it feels like Stack Overflow is being used as a redirect rather than a place to find answers to technical questions.

What is the community's stance on this situation? Is it okay to use Stack Overflow in this way, or should we expect redirecting to the repositories for more in-depth issues, such as library bugs and similar?

Comment: I would likely flag those comments as no longer needed in a heartbeat

Comment: It's noise at best, and should be flagged as such by using a "No longer needed" flag. If it's a repetitive issue, then you could raise a custom mod flag on one of the users **posts** and explain the problem; a mod may choose to reach out to them and ask them to stop. [so] isn't GitHub, and it strives to have answers here; that the answer is available elsewhere is irrelevant.

Comment: "*On the other hand, it feels like StackOverflow is being used as a redirect rather than a place to find answers to technical questions.*" or is it the case that the questions should have never been asked on SO in the first place? If it's really a support matter for a library, then I'd expect it to be over at the correct place for this. Which isn't the Q&A format of SO. To be clear, I don't know what the case is. But as always, I'm wary of being fed a one-sided view. Yes, maybe you're right and these are inappropriate comments. Or maybe they aren't.

Comment: Looking at a few of the questions (It's not difficult to find the user/comments in question with a little know how), they don't look like they are off-topic in my opinion, but I'm no SME.

Comment: @VLAZ the questions generally speaking comply with the SO standards. I am more inclined to think that the library maintainers are trying to push users to ask the questions towards their official support site. As I mentioned, that is reasonable for concrete stuff such as bug reporting. But I am asking about general Q&A like any other tag.

Comment: In the more general case (where the external producer may be GitHub or commercial or any other type of producer, and where it seems like the type of problem the vendor should be equipped to deal with), I tend to prompt people with whether they contacted the producer's support team first. Sometimes that's a no (SO is faster and bigger audience), sometimes that's a yes (they are unresponsive or gave unsatisfactory answers). In the latter case, obviously, it's quite expected that peers might be a valid second option.

Comment: @PhilipCouling Bug reports can be debugging questions. We’ve got quite a few questions to which the answer is "that is a bug".

Comment: @PhilipCouling I cannot give you a complete and definitive list, however, "how to use technology" can turn into a FR or a bug report. While being a perfectly rational question before that. It may happen that the answer is "You're right you should be able to do X but you actually cannot because <problem/not made yet>". As opposed to the question being "Please fix/implement X". So there are some question which might be appropriate on both SO and the vendor's place. They aren't *a lot* but they exist.

Comment: @PhilipCouling "Bug reports ask for a fix, SO questions ask to explain behaviour." Erm, no? Debugging questions very much ask for fixes. Whether the fix is to be located in user or library code if often not known to the asker, and thus such questions work both ways.

Comment: @PhilipCouling Well, if you see as a bug report only those formally being a bug report and nothing else, then I agree you are 100% correct.  And completely missing the mark to boot. In practice, many bug reports are "if I do this then it fails like that", which is [perfectly fine on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49940813/pip-no-module-named-internal) as well.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi It's unclear what mark you think I'm missing. Bug reports should at least have tried to rule out the reporter's own code being to blame. That's what I'm saying the difference between SO questions and bug reports are. Few library vendors would want unfiltered requests for "my code doesn't work" that have not tried to rule out their own mistake first. I'm unclear on what you think the counter to that is. You think we *should* throw every failed attempt to use a library straight over to the libraries author?

Comment: @PhilipCouling we expect the same from debugging questions: Debug and research until they cannot proceed anymore. That the *should* is all too often ignored applies to both SO and bug reports. "You think we should throw every failed attempt to use a library straight over to the libraries author?“ No, I‘m pointing out that something can be both a bug report and "debugging question" and thus shouldn’t be thrown out of either.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi okay so I know this is a subtle point, but these two things are different. We expect users to try to answer their own question and fix their own code first (Yes). Bug reports require the user to be confident [to a point] that the problem is not with their own code. It's perfectly legitimate for a user to try to work their own problem and then still not feel certain enough for a bug report. In those cases a user can chose to ask a question on SO first (they might not even suspect a bug). The devil is in the detail. Please don't conflate them.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

If the questions are off-topic on Stack Overflow and cannot be answered, then a comment pointing to where they can be answered is appropriate. It should always be accompanied by a close vote.

If the question is perfectly suitable for Stack Overflow, then the comments are useless noise and should be removed. Flag them as no longer needed. If this happens often enough to be a nuisance, you can raise a custom mod flag asking moderators to talk to the user.

Comment: If it is repeatedly posted, shouldn't the links be edited into the tag description I wonder. We should be lenient with such comments because there is no other effective way to communicate such information to people, but if it becomes someone's job to continuously do it then it is not sustainable.

Comment: @Gimby if instructions in wikis worked, tags that say "DO NOT USE" wouldn't be used. And yes, some tag wikis also include coordinates for where to ask support-type questions. Those are also not always respected.

Comment: Yeah but as the halfway measure you could then simply link to the tag wiki from the comment rather than having to duplicate the comment. Heck if we did that more, maybe they would become less invisible over time. Over a long, looong time.

Answer (score 19):

I think it is fine when it's done in moderation, and for good reasons.

For example, I answer a lot of questions about the Firebird DBMS ([firebird](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firebird)), but there are questions I know I can't answer, and where I know it is unlikely they'll receive an answer here on Stack Overflow because there are maybe 2 or 3 other people actively answering Firebird specific questions here, and the question doesn't seem to fall in their area of expertise either. Or, I know the type of question will result in a lot of back-and-forth for troubleshooting, making it unsuitable for Stack Overflow. In those cases I will usually refer them to a specific support list in the hope/expectation they'll find help there. On occasion, if the OP actually followed my advice and got an answer elsewhere, and if I remember, and think it's helpful, I'll post a community wiki answer summarizing the answer they received elsewhere.

I'll also post comments to direct them elsewhere when I know a question is off-topic, but can get answers elsewhere. I think doing so is acceptable, because the end result is the OP gets help.

Comment: Whenever I direct someone to an official support channel, it is normally because it requires some knowledge of an abstracted away component that the public/end-user can't see. The Firebase team encourage asking on SO as a first point of call, but sometimes their queries need to be redirected back to the internal teams. Even so, when directing a user offsite, it is almost always accompanied by something along the lines of "If you get a response worth sharing, consider self-answering your question for future users." (cont.)

Comment: It gets the OP an answer and normally still results in contributions here on SO. Then as said above, I delete the comment when an answer comes back as long as it doesn't mess up the comment thread or someone else marks it no longer needed when I forget.

Comment: @samthecodingman I realise now that I don't do that consistently. It is indeed a good idea to ask the user to post their own answer if they found it elsewhere (though to be honest, I think the success rate of that will be pretty low, as in, a lot of users will be interested in solving their problem, and unfortunately not in sharing back the solution).

Answer (score -2):

There seems to be a genuine point of confusion for some (hinted at [in comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/423095/should-users-repeatedly-redirect-askers-to-an-external-site-for-official-support/423152#comment946486_423095)), between bug reports and debugging requests.

This confusion is understandable because the two can look very similar. *"I did this and got that result when I wanted another result"* is a central theme of both.  Indeed a debugging request can result in a subsequent bug report with nearly identical text.

On face value, the only difference between them sometimes might be where they are posted. Although SO does prompt people to **ask a question** where bug reports are **making a statement**.

---

The two are not the same:

**Debug requests** start from a point where the OP is unsure of whether the behaviour they see is caused by their own misunderstanding or caused by a bug in the technology. It need expresses no opinion on whether its their own code or the librarie's code that should change.

**Bug reports and feature requests** *should* start from a point of some certainty. The OP is expressing an opinion that the libraries behaviour should change in some way.

---

Stackoverflow is not a vehicle for asking technology authors to change their software. Therefore bug reports and feature requests are off topic here and should be closed.

Stackoverflow is regularly used for debugging requests. And they are on topic.

Again even if the text of both matches, the **purpose** is totally different.

Just to confuse this further, GitHub has a Q/A feature for some projects. This acts as a direct competitor to SO and redirecting users there might be construed as spam, just like redirecting to any other competitor forum.

---

Even if this text of subsistent bug reports matches a debugging request here on SO, or the answer is "that's a bug", debugging requests are a completely different step.

As a general rule it's better for a developer to assume they made some mistake before believing that third party software is to blame.  The third party software usually has many other users hitting the same code path, so finding something they didn't is less likely.

---

Why would users be encouraging the opposite?

It's natural human behaviour to want some attention and human interaction for the thing you built.  Authors of libraries that have lower user bases may not see the danger.

There may even be some dislike of SO on the part of the author.

However authors of heavily used libraries will thank you NOT to conflate debugging requests with bug reports.  They simply do not want to be inundated with "spam" caused by other people's misunderstandings and other people's broken code.

---

Assuming that the original questions are not true bug reports or feature requests, then users should generally not be suggesting posting questions outside of SE. The only exception may be SO's own specific scope.

As others have pointed out, such comments ought to be flagged.